# HTML table ignoring element-style width

Tags: html, html-table

### HTML table ignoring element-style width

I have an HTML table where certain cells have very long text contents.

I want to specify a width (in pixels) for these cells using jQuery, but the rendered table just ignores the given width.

Is there any way to force the table to respect this width?

Thanks!

---

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/sangil/6hejy/35/

*(If you inspect the cell you can see the the computed width is different than the element-style width)*

---

**HTML**:

```
<div id="tblcont" class="tblcont">
 <table id="pivot_table">
 <tbody>
   <tr>
      <th id="h0" >product</th>
      <th id="h1" >price</th>
      <th id="h2" >change</th>
   </tr>         
   <tr>
      <!-- this is the cell causing trouble -->
      <td id="c00" >Acer 2400 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</td>
      <td id="c01" >3212</td>
      <td id="c02" >219</td>         

   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td id="c10" >Acer</td>
      <td id="c11" >3821</td>
      <td id="c12" >206</td>         

   </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

---

**CSS**:

```
.tblcont {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
  overflow-x: scroll; 
  border-spacing:0; 
  width: 100%;
}

th, td {
 overflow: hidden;
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 word-wrap: break-word;
}

th {
 height: 50px;
}
```

---

​**Javascript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // THIS LINE HAS NO EFFECT!
  $('#c00').width(30);
});​
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see from your fiddle that you already have a good grasp on how to get the word truncation and such in-place. I think you may find it useful to do something like the following:

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 30px;" /> <!-- this style affects the whole 1st column -->
    <col />
    <col />
  </colgroup>

  <!-- the rest of your table here -->
</table>
```

This method works with the HTML specification in a way that is compliant - and will resize the whole column. If you instead change the `display` of the cell to `inline-block`, as mentioned above, what will happen is that you take the cell out of the table's flow - and other stylistic changes may cease working.

By styling the entire `col` using the code above, you use the `table` element's `table-layout: fixed` styling to your advantage instead.

Additionally - I noticed that you have the cells set up to use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` Check out [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html) on quirksmode to understand why it's not working. The fix you need is to make the following edit:

```
th, td {
    border: solid #4682B4 1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center;

    white-space: nowrap; /* Add this line */
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution - although I think it would be simpler to just change the width of the header using its id rather than adding a colgroup (which I should have thought of to begin with :-/ ) Thanks!

Comment: "width" is non-standard/obsolete.

Comment: True - I've updated my answer to reflect what should be done in HTML5+.

Answer (score 6):

Table cells by default fit to their content and ignore your width.

Other possibility to the already provided answers:

Surround the text with some other container:

```
<td id="c00" ><div>Acer 2400 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div></td>
```

And change its width:

```
$('#c00 div').width(30);
```

Comment: This is a very workable solution, too. I don't think it quite fits what he's going for - but nested-elements is a trick I use often. You can then do things like toggling styling of the nested item on `:hover` and have the inner element pop out like a tooltip, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few issues:

`table-layout: fixed` tells the columns to be equal.

Then, even if you take that out, your text is wider than 30 pixels, with no spaces, so it's not going to go narrower than that `"aaaaaaaaaa"` etc. You'll need to make the text smaller, or add spaces.

Finally, `width` should be `"30px"` (in quotes).

Hope that helps.

Comment: If you look closer, he actually has the cells set up to truncate with ellipsis. He's trying to get the text to truncate when the column is too narrow.

Comment: Just noticed that you have 'word-wrap: break-word' on, which I guess should allow it to break. (I've never used it, so I'm not sure why that part might not be working.)

Comment: The big magic should be coming from the `tr, td { }` css style he's got going on. The `break-word` rule will be applied, but won't actually do anything. The `text-overflow: ellipsis;` and `overflow: hidden;` are the part that will alter things - by truncating the words before they flow outside the rendering boxes, and adding `...` at the end. He's just missing `white-space: nowrap;` to make it work.

Comment: Thanks, Troy - was just doing a drive-by working on another issue, and should have read more carefully.

Comment: np :) saw that you mentioned not knowing quite how that rule worked, so I thought I would point it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#c00').css("width","30px");
```

or this:

```
<td id="c00" style='width:30px'>
```

If you are using IE, you may need to have Compatability Mode on. Also, make sure you are importing the proper jQuery plugin.

Comment: There is no need for jQuery to solve this - it's a pure CSS issue.

Comment: you said: I want to specify a width (in pixels) for these cells using jQuery, but the rendered table just ignores the given width.
Is there any way to force the table to respect this width?

Comment: you can also put a style inline: <td id="c00" style='width:30px'>

Comment: I need to use jQuery in order to dynamically change the column width. As Troy noted though, the problem was I was trying to change the cell width directly rather than using the header or a colgroup.