# Split table in two keeping same column width

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to split a table -- i.e., rip off the `thead` and put it in its own table. Here's what I've got so far:

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/UPeN3/)

```
var $colgroup = $('<colgroup>');

$('td,th', '.query-results tr:first').each(function () {
    $colgroup.append($('<col>').width($(this).outerWidth()));
});

$('<table>')
    .insertBefore('.query-results')
    .append($colgroup)
    .append(
$('.query-results thead'));

$('.query-results').prepend($colgroup.clone());
```

I can't seem to get the column widths to be respected though; the tables never line up. I tried using colgroups [like this guy said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13073537/65387), but that doesn't seem to have an effect either.

What could be wrong?

[Using the width attribute](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/UPeN3/1/) doesn't change anything either.

Comment: Preliminary tests seem to suggest that setting the table width makes it work: http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/UPeN3/11/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to set the table width in order for the column widths to be respected.

```
var $colgroup = $('<colgroup>')

var tableWidth = $('.query-results').width();

$('td,th','.query-results tr:first').each(function() {
   $colgroup.append($('<col>').attr('width',parseInt($(this).outerWidth())));
});

$('<table>')
    .width(tableWidth)
    .insertBefore('.query-results')
    .append($colgroup)
    .append(
        $('.query-results thead')
    );

$('.query-results').width(tableWidth).prepend($colgroup.clone());
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/UPeN3/11/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to to make a scrollable table with a fixed header have a look here:

http://salzerdesign.com/test/fixedTable.html

Comment: I am, but none of the plugins I have tried worked for me, and nor does that one. Doesn't look like it supports horizontal scrolling.